# SQL TOP 10 Order by Count in Sub Query with IF

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query with some parameters and based on the parameters I need to run a different query each time.

For example:

```
 declare @daterangeint
 set @daterange = '7'

 If @date range !=0 (Select TOP 10 value,Count * from a where columna = ab group by value)
 ELSE (Select TOP 10 value,Count * from a where columnb = abcd group by value)
```

I need the top 10 counts in descending order for each query otherwise there will be too many rows returned. I understand you can't use order by within the query and order by doesn't seem to work outside of it so how would I tackle this.

This is my actual query

```
declare @assignedto nvarchar(256)
declare @createdrange int

set @assignedto = 'user'
set @createdrange = '7'

IF (@createdrange != 0)  (
    SELECT TOP 10
        COUNT(sr.Id_9A505725_E2F2_447F_271B_9B9F4F0D190C) AS 'wicount',
        (u.Department_312201FE_C1B3_E95A_01DF_E132E9BD3EC9, 'No Department') as Department 
    FROM 
        MTV_System$WorkItem$Incident sr 
    LEFT JOIN 
        RelationshipView r ON r.SourceEntityId = sr.BaseManagedEntityId 
                           AND r.RelationshipTypeId = 'DFF9BE66-38B0-B6D6-6144-A412A3EBD4CE'   
                           AND r.IsDeleted ='0'
    LEFT JOIN  
        MTV_System$Domain$User u ON r.TargetEntityId = u.BaseManagedEntityId
    INNER JOIN 
        RelationshipView assr ON assr.SourceEntityId = sr.BaseManagedEntityId 
                              AND assr.RelationshipTypeId = '15E577A3-6BF9-6713-4EAC-BA5A5B7C4722'  
                              AND assr.IsDeleted ='0'
    INNER JOIN 
        MTV_System$Domain$User assu ON assr.TargetEntityId = assu.BaseManagedEntityId 
                                    AND assu.UPN_7641DFF7_7A20_DC04_FC1C_B6FA8715DA02 = @assignedto        
    WHERE  
        sr.ResolvedDate_D2A4C73F_01B8_29C5_895B_5BE4C3DFAC4E >= dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, GetutcDate()) - @createdrange, 0) 
    GROUP BY 
        u.Department_312201FE_C1B3_E95A_01DF_E132E9BD3EC9
) ELSE (
    SELECT TOP 10
        COUNT(sr.Id_9A505725_E2F2_447F_271B_9B9F4F0D190C) AS 'wicount',
        COALESCE(u.Department_312201FE_C1B3_E95A_01DF_E132E9BD3EC9, 'No Department') as Department 
    FROM 
        MTV_System$WorkItem$Incident sr 
    LEFT JOIN 
        RelationshipView r ON r.SourceEntityId = sr.BaseManagedEntityId 
                           AND r.RelationshipTypeId = 'DFF9BE66-38B0-B6D6-6144-A412A3EBD4CE'  
                           AND r.IsDeleted ='0'
    LEFT JOIN  
        MTV_System$Domain$User u ON r.TargetEntityId = u.BaseManagedEntityId
    INNER JOIN 
        RelationshipView assr ON assr.SourceEntityId = sr.BaseManagedEntityId 
                              AND assr.RelationshipTypeId = '15E577A3-6BF9-6713-4EAC-BA5A5B7C4722'  
                              AND assr.IsDeleted ='0'
    INNER JOIN 
        MTV_System$Domain$User assu ON assr.TargetEntityId = assu.BaseManagedEntityId 
                                    AND assu.UPN_7641DFF7_7A20_DC04_FC1C_B6FA8715DA02 = @assignedto        
    WHERE 
        sr.Status_785407A9_729D_3A74_A383_575DB0CD50ED NOT IN ('2B8830B6-59F0-F574-9C2A-F4B4682F1681', 'BD0AE7C4-3315-2EB3-7933-82DFC482DBAF')
    GROUP BY
        u.Department_312201FE_C1B3_E95A_01DF_E132E9BD3EC9
)
```

Comment: You can use `order by` in each select ...

Comment: When you omit an order by with a TOP you have no way of knowing which rows you will get. To make it more enjoyable it will not be consistent either. To eliminate this frustration simple add an order by to every query that uses a TOP.

Comment: " I understand you can't use order by within the query"   ...huh?   sez who?

Comment: If I put order by in the subquery it say's its not recognised

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the switching criteria into the Where clause and use only one query:

```
SELECT TOP 10 
  COUNT(sr.Id_9A505725_E2F2_447F_271B_9B9F4F0D190C) wicount,
       (u.Department_312201FE_C1B3_E95A_01DF_E132E9BD3EC9, 'No Department') Department 
FROM MTV_System$WorkItem$Incident sr 
LEFT JOIN RelationshipView r 
   ON r.SourceEntityId = sr.BaseManagedEntityId 
     AND r.RelationshipTypeId = 'DFF9BE66-38B0-B6D6-6144-A412A3EBD4CE' 
     AND  r.IsDeleted ='0'
LEFT JOIN  MTV_System$Domain$User u 
   ON r.TargetEntityId = u.BaseManagedEntityId
JOIN RelationshipView assr 
   ON assr.SourceEntityId = sr.BaseManagedEntityId 
      AND assr.RelationshipTypeId = '15E577A3-6BF9-6713-4EAC-BA5A5B7C4722'
      AND  assr.IsDeleted ='0'
JOIN MTV_System$Domain$User assu 
   ON assr.TargetEntityId = assu.BaseManagedEntityId 
     AND assu.UPN_7641DFF7_7A20_DC04_FC1C_B6FA8715DA02 = @assignedto        
WHERE (@createdrange = '7' And
      sr.ResolvedDate_D2A4C73F_01B8_29C5_895B_5BE4C3DFAC4E 
         >= dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,GetutcDate())-@createdrange,0)) Or
      (@createdrange != '7' And
      sr.Status_785407A9_729D_3A74_A383_575DB0CD50ED 
         NOT IN ('2B8830B6-59F0-F574-9C2A-F4B4682F1681',
                 'BD0AE7C4-3315-2EB3-7933-82DFC482DBAF'))
GROUP BY u.Department_312201FE_C1B3_E95A_01DF_E132E9BD3EC9
Order By [Whatever ordering you want to determine top 10]
```

Comment: that works, my bad had a rouge character in the parameter

Answer (score 0):

Include the filter criteria to be evaluated with other where clause statements.

```
 Select TOP 10 value,Count * from a 
 where 
 (@daterange<>7 OR columna=abcd)
 AND
 (@daterange<>0 OR columna=ab)
 group by value
```

I prefer null evaluations as it is easier to understand to me.

```
INT @CreatedDateRange=NULL

 WHERE  
 (@CreatedDateRange IS NULL OR sr.ResolvedDate_D2A4C73F_01B8_29C5_895B_5BE4C3DFAC4E >=dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,GetutcDate())-@createdrange,0) 
 AND 
 (NOT @CreatedDateRange IS NULL OR sr.Status_785407A9_729D_3A74_A383_575DB0CD50ED NOT IN ('2B8830B6-59F0-F574-9C2A-F4B4682F1681','BD0AE7C4-3315-2EB3-7933-82DFC482DBAF')
```

Comment: that works, my bad had a rouge character in the parameter

Comment: This is the best way to go about condensing your two queries into one based on where clause filters. However, you may need to play around with the variables and or bool logic.